# SEO friendly for multiple page with multiple parameter

Tags: .htaccess, seo

pls help me how to create a .htaccess file as

```
    index.php?regional=aaa domain.com/aaa/
    list.php?regional=aaa&ctg=bbb&orderby=ccc&page=123 domain.com/list/aaa/bbb/ccc/123/
    list.php?regional=aaa&ctg=bbb&orderby=ccc domain.com/list/aaa/bbb/ccc/
    list.php?regional=aaa&ctg=bbb domain.com/list/aaa/bbb/ 
    detail.php?regional=aaa&ctg=bbb&name=ddd domain.com/detail/aaa/ddd/
```

Comment: You explained what's your source but forgot to specify how you want to transform them.

Comment: I wanna change into like this

index.php?regional=aaa into domain.com/aaa/
list.php?regional=aaa&ctg=bbb&orderby=ccc&page=123 into domain.com/list/aaa/bbb/ccc/123/
list.php?regional=aaa&ctg=bbb&orderby=ccc into domain.com/list/aaa/bbb/ccc/
list.php?regional=aaa&ctg=bbb into domain.com/list/aaa/bbb/
detail.php?regional=aaa&ctg=bbb&name=ddd into domain.com/detail/aaa/ddd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$                             index.php?regional=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^list/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ list.php?regional=$1&ctg=$2&orderby=$3&page=$4 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^list/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$         list.php?regional=$1&ctg=$2&orderby=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^list/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$                 list.php?regional=$1&ctg=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$                             index.php?regional_code=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^list/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ list.php?regional_code=$1&ctg=$2&orderby=$3&page=$4 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^list/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$         list.php?regional_code=$1&ctg=$2&orderby=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^list/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$                 list.php?regional_code=$1&ctg=$2 [NC,L]

this is the last updated which I based upon baynezy. I added "/" between ^list and ([^/]+). Thank you so much baynezy. I'm really thank to you.